# serializing polymorphic classes using spray.json getting could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type

Tags: scala, spray

I am trying to produce json

```
trait Bar
case class Foo(name:String) extends Bar
case class Buz(name:String,age:Int) extends Bar
case class Responsive(id:String ,bars:List[Bar])
```

when calling

```
import spray.json._
val foo  = Foo("foo")
val fooRes  = Responsive("abc",List(foo))

println(fooRes.toJson)
```

I am getting

```
Cannot find JsonWriter or JsonFormat type class for com.demo.Responsive
          println(s" res = ${fooRes.toJson}")
                                    ^
```

when I add

```
implicit val impResponsive = jsonFormat2(Responsive)
```

I am getting

```
`could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type` com.demo.routing.JsonImplicits.JF[List[com.avi.demo.Bar]]
 implicit val impResponsive = jsonFormat2(Responsive)
                                          ^
```

why am I getting these errors ? how can I solve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you get on `Responsive` is really due to the fact that this class contains a reference to `Bar` and to the fact you don't have a (de-)serialiser for the `Bar` trait. More in detail, the type-system knows that you can (de-)serialise instances of `Foo`, `Buz` and `Responsive` because you have the appropriate formats in scope. But how can the type-system know that you can (de-)serialise a generic `Bar`?

It would be great if spray-json could support this use case making the `Bar` trait sealed and defining the serialisers for its children, but I am afraid that this wouldn't work either. In the end you will need to write a custom serialiser for the `Bar` trait. If you want a proof that the error is due to this just add the following to your implicit formats:

```
implicit val barFormat: RootJsonFormat[Bar] = ???
```

Everything should compile now, but obviously fail at runtime due to the `???`.